# Counting every second page in pagenumbering

Tags: page-numbering

In some old Medieval books every second page (so, every leaf of the book) was counted.
How could I do this in TeX?

Comment: TeX or LaTeX? Package or not? How did you specify the header? Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: Additional relevant information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\thepage{\the\numexpr(\value{page}+1)/2\relax}
```